# MySQL return a blank row every other row from a select?

Tags: mysql

I'm wondering if there is a way for a select statement to return an empty row (or a row with all empty values for each column) every other row, so that I can avoid doing this after exporting the results from MySQL.

I've been unable to do so any way I could think of, and google leads me no where.

Comment: You do realize it's not database's job to return empty rows? It's supposed to handle data and return results based on query you provide, not style the results too. You need to use a programming language to do that for you or the program you export data with.

Comment: You want to select empty rows out of a database?
Why do you actually want to do that?
And what empty values? null values? I honestly don't understand it.

Comment: From what I gathered, he requires that each row that contains data gets appended with empty row so that the styling in program used for exporting is right. If I'm wrong feel free to correct me.

Comment: Michael J.V. is right, and yes, I realize it's not it's job - but it saves a step for the people who I send this data too, and if it's possible to do it in the select query that gets the data, I'd prefer to remove that step for them.

Comment: Aha well then i am afraid i won't be of mutch help because i don't know of any sql code to accomplice that.

Comment: @This Guy - that's why you need to create a program that will format the results the DB spits out. I don't know whether you created the program you use to export data with or not, however you can probably create a simple script that pulls the records out and then appends empty rows where needed.

Answer (score 2):

Lets say I have a table `user` with 3 columns: `user_id`, `user_name` and `password`. Here is a method using a `LEFT JOIN` to select a row of `null` values for every columns of a table without specifying the columns individually in the `SELECT`:

```
SELECT u.*
FROM (SELECT null) a
LEFT JOIN `user` u
ON false;
```

This query will return:

```
+---------+-----------+----------+
| user_id | user_name | password |
+---------+-----------+----------+
|    NULL |      NULL |     NULL |
+---------+-----------+----------+
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure I got what you want. Are you looking for something like `SELECT * FROM table1 LIMIT 0` ?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes this is really necessary, such as when using a database for applications.

Use just:

```
select 0 limit 0;
```

Comment: This was useful for me because I couldn't select from an existing table.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely ancient question I know, but I had the same requirement.  I managed to achieve what I wanted by joining on the required table with a sub-select and `union`ing a blank row, like so (the "question" is also only returned for the first option to aid formatting of the report)...

```
SELECT IF( o.order_by = 1, q.question, '' ), o.option_text FROM questions q
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT option_text, order_by, question_id FROM options
    UNION
    SELECT '', 999999, ''
    ORDER BY order_by DESC
) o ON q.id = o.`question_id` OR o.option_text = ''
WHERE q.category_id = 123;
```

Not pretty or perfect (nor the intended job of a database), but it works.

Answer (score 0):

(note: I cannot leave comments yet, so I'm posting this here)
Maybe this will help you get started?

You would have to find a way to loop through this:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM table LIMIT 1 UNION SELECT "", "", "";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
set @i := 0;
set @j := 1;

select c1
from (
    select c1, @i := @i + 2 as o
    from my_table
    union
    select '' as c1, @j := @j + 2 as o
    from my_table
) ss
order by o
;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3
FROM (
      SELECT dummy, col1, col2, col3
      FROM (
        SELECT col1 AS dummy, col1, col2, col3
        FROM dumbtask
        ORDER BY col1
       ) t1
       UNION ALL
       (
        SELECT col1 AS dummy, NULL AS col1, NULL AS col2, NULL AS col3
        FROM dumbtask
        ORDER BY dummy
       )
      ORDER BY dummy) t3;
```

I have to say though ... this is one of the most stupid tasks that I've seen lately.

Comment: You doubled each line and ordered by a column. It will not work because the resulting order from two (or more) equal values is not determined. And it is badly written.

Comment: There should be a unique key(unless the database design is as bad as the task to complete), so the equal values problem is not an issue. It's just an example anyway - I don't know if there are other fields or which one to use in the `ORDER BY` statement. Are you seriously complaining that an answer to THIS question is badly written? :D

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Select, it is possible just place

```
values row(null)
```

or

```
values row('Or', 'any', 'other'), row('rows','and','columns')
```